# How do I set the background color of a GTK listbox?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk, gtk3

I want to do this to workaround a problem with running a GTK application on Ubuntu 16.04 vs Ubuntu 18.04. For me it seems that listboxes have a white background on 18.04 but are transparent/same color as background on 16.04. I don't like the inconsistency caused by running the same app on different versions of Ubuntu. Perhaps I could resolve this issue by strictly setting the background color of the listbox to white.

Suppose I initialize a listbox like this:

```
GtkWidget *List = gtk_list_box_new();
```

How do I set the background color, for example, in RGB style?

Comment: Did you try both compiling and running in 16.04?

Comment: It's not supposed to work this way. You're supposed to get the value returned by g_timeout_add_seconds, which is the id of the GSource this function created. Then to stop that source, either you return FALSE in the callback it calls, or you call g_source_remove with your source id as a parameter. Read the documentation for [`g_timeout_add_seconds`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) and [`g_source_remove`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-remove).